# Why do we need OperationAuthorizationRequirement for resource-based authorization in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was reading **[Resource-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-3.1#feedback)** on learn.microsoft.com and I am confused about complexity required to check author of a document.

In this example we need to create **Operations** and **DocumentAuthorizationCrudHandler** classes, register DI in **Startup**, call and await **AuthorizeAsync** and then perform checks.

Instead of writing 30 lines of code in 4 files we can accomplish everything in just one line of code

```
if (User.Identity?.Name == Document.Author) return Page();
```

If we want be able to reuse this we can extract it to a method and still it will be far less complicated solution.

Is there anything wrong with one line solution or I am missing something?

**Edit:**

To clarify my question - Is there any concrete example why would it be better to implement AuthorizationHandler and OperationAuthorizationRequirement for resource authorization instead of going with simple check? I am genuinely curious about what are the benefits, because I prefer simple solutions but I am afraid that I will hit some case in future that is already covered by AuthorizationHandler/OperationAuthorizationRequirement.

Answer (score 2):

As the doc has said that `Operations` and `DocumentAuthorizationCrudHandler` classes enable you to write a single handler instead of an individual class for each operation type.

> If we want be able to reuse this we can extract it to a method and still it will be far less complicated solution.

The recommended recourse-based authorization uses DI,which could be more clear and powerful, instead of repeating if / else code everywhere.

Besides,we could also handle different status code (401,403...) in the custom Authorization Handler.We could use `IAuthorizationService` on view or in blazor razor component.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Actually the example on Microsoft site is repeating if/else code everywhere. If this wasn't the case then I would be fine with using AuthorizationHandler. Also the entire Operations class in the example looks like some hack to mimic Enum...